# Batch Search directories/files for several separate strings with results for each string

Tags: windows, search

I would like to recursively search through a parent directory and all sub directories for several separate strings and show the results for each string. For example:

**Text To Search For**

```
Foo
Bar
Fizz
Buzz
(list continues for several hundred words)
```

**Results Pane**

```
Foo
  - Found in files x, y, z
Bar
  - Found in files x, y
Fizz
  - Not found in any files
Buzz
  - Found in files y, z
```

**Summary**
I have a list of several hundred strings that I will have to search for several times. It is a tedious process to search for individual strings and I'm looking for a way to perform this in a batch process.

Are there any Windows programs that can perform this type of search?

**FWIW**
I've tried with notepad++ and Visual Studio, but haven't quite found a way to meet the requirements of showing each string as a separate result.

Answer (score 3):

The below batch script would do this.

```
@echo off

for /F %%i in (pattern.txt) do (
echo Files containing %%i
findstr /M /C:%%i /S *.txt
)
```

For the case of string not present in any of the files, it does not print the statement you wanted. Instead, it prints an empty list of files.
source: [Findstr command](http://www.windows-commandline.com/findstr-command-examples-regular/)

Answer (score 1):

[Grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) is your friend. You can put the patterns to look for into a file called patterns.txt and then run something like the following:

```
grep -f patterns.txt -r * > ..\results.txt
```

Edit:

Just came across a [question about grep-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tool-for-windows) things available in Windows. The question and answers cover lots of free and non-free standalone tools and commands built-in to e.g. Powershell.

Comment: Grep would probably work with a bit of wrestling of the switches. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Actually all the switches are shown. '-f filename' is the list of patterns in a file and '-r' is for recursive. The output is very close to what you specified as the goal. The patterns.txt should have a pattern per line.

Answer (score 1):

The [Swiss File Knife](http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html) has a command "hexfind" which can search any number of patterns in parallel. Create a search pattern file "mypatterns.txt" containing:

```
/Foo/
/Bar/
/Fizz/
/Buzz/
```

And to search all files of folder mydir, including all subfolders, type:

```
sfk hexfind -bylist mypatterns.txt mydir
```

This will produce a dump of every single hit found, like:

```
testfiles\Formats\10-dir-list.txt : hit at offset 0x273
>4261724D 75672E68 70700D0A 433A5C73< BarMug.hpp..C:\s 00000273
testfiles\Formats\10-dir-list.txt : hit at offset 0x290
>466F6F42 616E6B5C 42617244 72697665< FooBank\BarDrive 00000290
```

To list only the filenames containing hits, add option -nodump.
This will not produce the exact results pane as you requested, but at least you see where your patterns occur.

If it's a problem to create mypatterns.txt with the // format, you can produce the file from a wordlist.txt like:

```
sfk filter wordlist.txt -form "/$col1/" +tofile mypatterns.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of Swiss File Knife and the great example.